# How to make a list of contents longer than the parent screen?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an engineering app that will have dozens of separate activities.  I want a contents page with buttons that link to each activity. I am able to code the buttons with no problem.

However, now that the list is getting longer I want it to be much longer than the screen. I need to be able to scroll down the list.

How could I go about this?

Comment: read about `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Use 'ScrollView' around your 'LinearLayout'

Comment: Please understand that your question boils down to "please help me resolving my complex problem". But we do not regard such requests as valid questions (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) for details).

Comment: Thanks @pskink .  much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @KrzysztofKubicki.

Comment: Apologies @GhostCat. This is my first post. I assumed it was a run of the mill problem and not a complex one.  Will post my attempted code next time and error messages etc.

Comment: Sure, just do better next time. And *when* there is a simple helpful answer, then your question is probably OK ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest solution for you is to wrap your `LinearLayout` with `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView with="match_parent .....>
    <LinearLayout width and height....>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Kubicki.  This works.